# Exercises on group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, big-list, group-actions

What are some difficult, challenging and fair exercises in group theory?
I know it is quite general, in particular I am referring to these areas of group theory:

- theory of automorphism
- group actions
- Sylow's theorem
- semi-direct products
- simple groups

(an exercise of the type I mean can be: " if p and q are distinct primes, show that a group of order $p^3q$ is not simple" or also "What is $Aut(Q)$? Where $Q$ the group of quaternions")

Comment: This is probably much too broad a question, but the later exercises in the first several chapters of Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra* will probably satisfy you at least partly.